# C++ dynamic_cast not return NULL

Tags: inheritance, null, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

'File' is my Base Class. Directory is derived. This function write in Directory Class.

```
bool Directory::addParentPatch(File &otherFile)
{
   if(NULL==dynamic_cast<Directory*> (&otherFile))
   {   
       otherFile.addPath((*this).path());
       return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

When I write the main, thats not work. Because dynamic_cast (&otherFile) not return NULL.

```
int main
{
    Directory dir1;
    Directory dir2;
    TextFile text1;

    dir1.addParentPatch(text1); //I want this return true
    dir1.addParentPatch(dir2); //I want this return false

}
```

dir1.addParentPatch(text1)

dir1.addParentPatch(dir2)

In both cases, return true. But ı dont want this. How fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as given, with the necessary glue added:

```
#include <iostream>

class File {
public:
    File() { }
    virtual ~File() { }
};

class Directory : public File {
public:
    Directory() { }
    bool addParentPatch (File &otherFile);
};

class TextFile : public File {
public:
    TextFile() { }
};

bool Directory::addParentPatch(File &otherFile)
{
   if(NULL==dynamic_cast<Directory*> (&otherFile))
       return true;

   return false;
}

int main ()
{
    Directory dir1;
    Directory dir2;
    TextFile text1;

    std::cout << dir1.addParentPatch(text1) << std::endl; //I want this return true
    std::cout << dir1.addParentPatch(dir2) << std::endl; //I want this return false
}
```

Output is

```
1
0
```

So you probably messed up some of the glue.